# Keep getting error in R " Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404."

Tags: r, web-scraping, data-mining

```
`library(rvest)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(stringr)


#Getting the number of Page
getPageNumber <- function(URL){
  parsedDocument = read_html(URL)
  Sort1 <- html_nodes(parsedDocument, 'div')
  Sort2 <- Sort1[which(html_attr(Sort1, "class") == "pagination al-pagination")] 
  P <- str_count(html_text(Sort2), pattern = " \\d+\r\n")
  return(ifelse(length(P) == 0, 0, max(P)))
}

#Getting all articles based off of their DOI
getAllArticles <-function(URL){
  parsedDocument = read_html(URL)
  Sort1 <- html_nodes(parsedDocument,'div')
  Sort2 <-  Sort1[which(html_attr(Sort1, "class") == "al-citation-list")]
  ArticleDOInumber = trimws(gsub(".*10.1093/dnares/","",html_text(Sort2)))
  URL3 <- "https://doi.org/10.1093/dnares/"
  URL4 <- paste(URL3, ArticleDOInumber, sep = "")
  return(URL4)
}


Title <- function(parsedDocument){
  Sort1 <- html_nodes(parsedDocument, 'h4')
  Title <- gsub("<a>\\n|\\n</a>","",Sort1)
  return(Title)
}



#main function with input as parameter year
findURL <- function(year_chosen){
  if(year_chosen >= 1994){
  noYearURL = glue::glue("https://academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/search-results?rg_IssuePublicationDate=01%2F01%2F{year_chosen}%20TO%2012%2F31%2F{year_chosen}")
  pagesURl = "&fl_SiteID=5275&page="
  URL = paste(noYearURL, pagesURl, sep = "")
  #URL is working with parameter year_chosen
  Page <- getPageNumber(URL)
  
  
  if(Page == 5){
    Page2 <- 0
    while(Page < Page2 | Page != Page2){
      Page <- Page2
      URL3 <- paste(URL, Page-1, sep = "")
      Page2 <- getPageNumber(URL3)  
    }
  }
  R_Data <- data.frame()
  for(i in 0:ifelse((Page-1) > 0, (Page-1), 0)){
  URL2 <- getAllArticles(paste(URL, i, sep = ""))
    for(j in 1:(length(URL2))){
      parsedDocument <- read_html(URL2[j])
      print(URL2[j])
      R <- data.frame("Title" = Title(parsedDocument), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      R_Data <- rbind(R_Data, R)
    } 
  }
  write.csv(R_Data, "Group4.csv", row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t")
  } else {
    print("The Year you provide is out of range, this journal only contain articles from 2005 to present")
  }
}

findURL(2000)`
```

So I am Trying to scrape a website for a given year and inside my main function I try to loop through different pages. Extracting just the title of each article.

I keep getting this error -> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404

Some years have only 3 pages so I can see why there may be an error for that, but mostly all have articles have at 5 pages of journals.

After  scraping the journals  by year  I want to write out the  scraped titles onto a  civ file .

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't fully checked i.e. not tested with lots of different years, but as Page = 0 yields no results do you perhaps want:

`for(i in 1:Page)`

instead of

`for(i in 0:ifelse((Page-1) > 0, (Page-1), 0))`

This possibly has implications for logic later in `findURL`.

Also, your function `Title` is currently returning html. Don't know if that was intentional.

With my suggested change your code now produces a populated csv with a lot of duplicated info suggesting you may want to revisit your `Title` function.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion that does do the same thing. I posted another question  and it's about my output  if you could take a look     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66757114/r-function-is-looping-over-the-same-data-in-webscraper

Comment: It doesn't produce a 404 for me like your original code did. Are you saying it does for you?

Comment: I restarted RStudio and the error went away thank you for the help!

Comment: QHarr if you can I  would appreciate assistance on this question I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66757114/r-function-is-looping-over-the-same-data-in-webscraper

Comment: What are you hoping to return from Title function?

Comment: The title function is supposed to scrape the title of  a journal entry. I believe my Title function is currently returning the title along with some html. That has to be fixed

Comment: No it is not.  I am just testing an adaptation to your code.