# R program is not outputting the correct scraped journal entries

Tags: r, loops, pdf, web-scraping, output

```html
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(stringr)


#Getting the number of Page
getPageNumber <- function(URL) {
  # print(URL)
  parsedDocument <- read_html(URL)
  pageNumber <- parsedDocument %>%
    html_node(".al-currentPage + a:last-child") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    as.integer()
  return(pageNumber)
}


#Getting all articles based off of their DOI
getAllArticles <-function(URL){
  parsedDocument = read_html(URL)
  findLocationDiv <- html_nodes(parsedDocument,'div')
  foundClass <-  findLocationDiv[which(html_attr(findLocationDiv, "class") == "al-citation-list")]
  ArticleDOInumber = trimws(gsub(".*10.1093/dnares/","",html_text(foundClass)))
  DOImain <- "https://doi.org/10.1093/dnares/"
  fullDOI <- paste(DOImain, ArticleDOInumber, sep = "")
  return(fullDOI)
}

CorrespondingAuthors <- function(parsedDocument){
  CorrespondingAuthors <- parsedDocument %>%
    html_node("a.linked-name js-linked-name-trigger") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    return(CorrespondingAuthors)
}

CoAuthorEmail <- function(parsedDocument){
  CoAuthorEmail <- parsedDocument %>%
    html_node(".icon-general-mail") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    return(CoAuthorEmail)
}
FullText <- function(parsedDocument){
  FullText <- parsedDocument %>%
    html_node('.PdfOnlyLink .article-pdfLink') %>% html_attr('href')
    return(FullText)
}

#main function with input as parameter year
findURL <- function(year_chosen){
  if (year_chosen >= 1994) {
    noYearURL <- glue::glue("https://academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/search-results?rg_IssuePublicationDate=01%2F01%2F{year_chosen}%20TO%2012%2F31%2F{year_chosen}")
    pagesURl <- "&fl_SiteID=5275&page="
    URL <- paste(noYearURL, pagesURl, sep = "")
    # URL is working with parameter year_chosen
    firstPage <- getPageNumber(URL)
    
    if (firstPage == 5) {
      nextPage <- 0
      while (firstPage < nextPage | firstPage != nextPage) {
        firstPage <- nextPage
        URLwithPageNum <- paste(URL, firstPage-1, sep = "")
        nextPage <- getPageNumber(URLwithPageNum)
      }
    }
  DNAresearch <- data.frame()
    for (i in 1:firstPage) {
      URLallArticles <- getAllArticles(paste(URL, i, sep = ""))
      for (j in 1:(length(URLallArticles))) {
        parsedDocument <- read_html(URLallArticles[j])
        #"Title" = Title(parsedDocument),"Authors" = Authors(parsedDocument),"Author Affiliations" = AuthorAffil(parsedDocument),"Corresponding  Authors" CorrespondingAuthors=(parsedDocument),"CoAuthor Email" = CoAuthorEmail(parsedDocument),"Publication Date" = PublicationDate(parsedDocument),"Keywords" = Keywords(parsedDocument),"Abstract" = Abstract(parsedDocument), "Full Text" = FullText(parsedDocument)
        allData <- data.frame("Corresponding Authors" = (parsedDocument),"CoAuthor Email" = CoAuthorEmail(parsedDocument),"Full Text" = FullText(parsedDocument),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        #for(i in 1:allData == "NA"){
          #i == "NO"
        #}
        DNAresearch <- rbind(DNAresearch, allData)
      }
    }
    write.csv(DNAresearch, "DNAresearch.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  } else {
    print("The Year you provide is out of range, this journal only contain articles from 2005 to present")
  }
}

##################### Main function test
findURL(1994)
```

In the program above I am scraping journals from a website. The output is then on a csv file named DNAresearch. I have three things that need to  be fixed.

1. In CorrespondingAuthors I keep getting the  first author of the  journal. I actually need  all of the  authors other than the  the first author.
2. In CoAuthorEmail I cannot find the authors emails so in the csv file it returns NA. It should output NA , as I believe the email is not referenced, however I  would like the CSV file to return NO instead of  NA.
3. In FullText I am trying to get the full text of the  journal. The full text has to be scraped through a pdf link. My csv currently returns NA .

Everything is correct, but the three issues I have above. Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an incomplete answer, it is just easier to than fitting all of this into a comment:

1. In order to return more than one node instead of the just the first node.  You need to use "html_node**s**" with the s.  This will return all of the nodes, but has the disadvantage is if the node is missing the function returns a zero length vector.  So if you are sure has an author, then it should be a problem

   ```
   CorrespondingAuthors <- function(parsedDocument){
     CorrespondingAuthors <- parsedDocument %>%
     html_nodes("a.linked-name js-linked-name-trigger") %>%
     html_text() 
     #probably need to add: CorrespondingAuthors  <- paste(CorrespondingAuthor, collapse =", ")
    return(CorrespondingAuthors)
   }
   ```
2. There is a difference between "NA" and NA.  The first is just a character string of N and A.  To check for the not available NA, it is better to use the `is.na()` function.
3. There are ways to download PDF files and extract the contents.  It is best to answer a new question that is strictly focus on that issue.  It is more likely to get answered and be a more useful resources in the future.

*UPDATE*
Based on the provide link in the comments here is a working CorrespondingAuthors and AuthorEmail

```
url <- "https://academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/article/25/6/655/5123538?searchresult=1"
page <- read_html(url)

    CorrespondingAuthors <- function(parsedDocument){
       CorrespondingAuthors <- parsedDocument %>%
          html_nodes("a.linked-name") %>%
          html_text() 
       #Comma separate string of names
       CorrespondingAuthors  <- paste(CorrespondingAuthors, collapse =", ")
       # Comment the above line for a vector names
       return(CorrespondingAuthors)
    }
    
    
   CoAuthorEmail <- function(parsedDocument){
      CoAuthorEmail <- parsedDocument %>%
           html_node("div.info-author-correspondence a") %>%
           html_text() 
      CoAuthorEmail <- ifelse(is.na(CoAuthorEmail), "No", CoAuthorEmail)
      return(CoAuthorEmail)
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the  comment. I've tried your code for part 1 and didn't get any outputs. For part 3 you added a piece of code in the previous comment and that too didn't work either. For the  check 'not  available' or NA it would pretty much be for  any part of the  webscrape where the csv  outputs  NA. For  CoAuthorEmail there's is no author email so the output in the csv is just NA

Comment: For part1 after trying out multiple ways of your function  the best I was able to do was create the column but only with  "NA". Your help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Okay so I realized that some journals based off the years have the authors email and some don't. This link https://academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/article/25/6/655/5123538?searchresult=1 actually has an email. So how could I fix this function to return the authors email if it is there and if not it would say "NO" for the output csv. Cheers and thanks for the help!!

Comment: Ok, provided an update.  For *CorrespondingAuthors*, the HTML selector was slightly off.     *CoAuthorEmail* fixed the selector and added an ifelse for No instead of NA

Comment: Thank you the  functions work well. Still need to work on  function  "Full Text". Also would you know why for some dates I try  to scrape I get this error 'rror in if (firstPage == 5) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed'  The error is referring too my second if statement in my  main function

Comment: The text of the articles is found in these nodes:  `html_nodes("a.linked-name")` It would take some work to read the heading and paragraphs to match the article format, but doable.  Concerning your error most likely your html selector in the "getpagenumber" function is not consistently returning the correct value.  Use a print statement to verify.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean for the "Full Text" function. If you  go to later dates like the year 1994 the journal is only available through pdf, which is why I figured I would just take in the pdf link and get the full text of  the pdf. Also, the error  doesn't occur for years like 1994. This is mainly why I am confused.